# Keycloak impersonate redirect_uri

Tags: keycloak

I've been using keycloak impersonate directly through the admin UI for keycloak, however recently i've decided to disable the user account screen in keycloak as I only update the user information through API calls from another application (to keep them in sync).

However now when I impersonate a user the redirect URI leads account/applications which now says "no access" due to the fact that I've disabled the account screen. I can navigate directly to my actual application that is protected by keycloak but its not an ideal experience for the support team I'll be handing this over to.

Is there any way to change the redirect_uri for impersonate to allow me to directly redirect them to the application page when they select impersonate from the admin UI.

Thanks!